# Canadian Province Shapefile

Tags: service, reporting, shapefile

Looking for a shapefile for Canadian provinces (North america would be acceptable too) for a Msft Reporting Services 2008 report. Anyone know a decent site where I can get my hands on these?

Comment: You might try asking on [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: Wow, is there a stackexchange for EVERYTHING? awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for Canadian geography to report on as well. It's not a small job. Anyhow, I was able to get a base map for Canada from StatsCan. They have lots of very cool data products that are handy in this area too.

Here's the link:
Free Census Subdivision Boundary Files

http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2006/geo/bound-limit-eng.cfm

Comment: Great website in general! Lots of statistical information too, for Canada, and links for everywhere else. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I use the "GeoBase Geopolitical boundaries - Level 1" that I got somewhere off of the Natural Resources Canada web site some years ago.

Comment: I spent a lot of time on Natural Resources and had a lot of trouble getting a base map.

Comment: Well, it hasn't been the same since it was Energy, Mines and Resources.